# how can access to ethereum smart contract via etherscan API

Tags: etherscan

i have problem to access via etherscan api to any contract. i verified the contract code and i do every step but when i want to access just give me a 0 number when have yo be 30000000.

url
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413

for example i want to read the totalSupply of that json.

UPDATE:
Solved